# tegra-K1 deviceQuery fails: CUDA driver version is insufficient

Tags: debian, nvidia, arm, proprietary-drivers

I run a Debian Jessie on a Tegra-K1 board (Toradex Apalis-TK1), installed the CUDA toolkit 7.0 and the `nvidia_drivers.tbz2` from the *Jetson TK1 21.5* package.

Now I get

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Oct_16_15:23:46_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.0, V7.0.70

$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia-tegra.conf 
/usr/lib/tegra

$ cat /etc/nv_tegra_release 
# R21 (release), REVISION: 5.0, GCID: 7273100, BOARD: ardbeg,  EABI: hard, DATE: Wed Jun  8 04:19:09 UTC 2016
50e7e42bde409d5ba0eb410d803b991cd6c4c32b */usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
cc612c5afcb8a76a5b847fc500d2354582d32abb */usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
e96a78d9c3947a980f065d96557f98c70500db17 */usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/tegra/libnvomxilclient.so
... and so on ...
```

I was able to build the `NVIDIA_CUDA-7.0_Samples` (using `make SMS=53` to [avoid linking problems](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/922876/dynamic-parallelism-on-tx1/?offset=3)), but

```
1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

How can I narrow the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the developer forum I found out: The error message is correct (this happens sometimes). Cuda toolkit 7 requires the R23 release of the cuda driver, but the latest release available for Tegra K1 is R21.

So you need an older toolkit version, but only version 7 is available for download on the nvidia site. Older versions are only accessible via JetPack, but JetPack is Ubuntu-only (fails to install on Debian).

But they gave me instructions to work around the problem:

- download JetPack 2.3.1
- extract the content of the archive: `bash JetPack-L4T-2.3.1-linux-x64.run –noexec`
- go to the `_installer` directory where you will find a `Chooser` binary
- `./Chooser` -> it may ask for a libpng12 so I installed this lib in my home then: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:path_to_libpng/lib` then retry `./Chooser`
- the GUI appears but this is not what is important: you may notice that a `repository.json` file is created which contains all the link to the cuda, etc packages. Just find the link corresponding to your CUDA version and that's it.

Download the `.deb` package from the URL given in the json file with `wget`, install it with `dpkg -i`, then

```
apt update
apt search cuda
apt install ...
```

Obviously, Nvidia wants us to head for TX1 and TX2, not stick to TK1 ...